# Magento 2 Update Cart Redirects To Homepage

Tags: magento2, cart, redirect

I've just moved our Magento website to a new server and for some reason the update cart button within the cart redirects the user back to the homepage.

Unsure why this is happening since it is working correctly on my local version and on the old server as it should.

Does anyone know whether this is server related or whether there is anyway to update the coding to ensure it stays on the cart when updating?

Any advice to be able to resolve this?

Comment: are you able to login on site , as customer / user ?

Comment: The issue appears even if logged in as customer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Nginx configuration.

Go to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/<configFileName>`

and comment *(add # in the beginning)* the following lines:

- add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin';
- add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'strict-origin';

After that restart nginx and clear cache.

It should work.

Comment: In magento nginx.conf.sample there is no Referrer-Policy. I added and removed this lines, but without changes

Comment: Hello shaandg i am facing same issue but still i could not fix can you help me I have done your mention steps but it is not working because that you have mentioned header it is not there in conf file